# A basis for matrix $A$ is $B$, theorem application?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

If a basis for matrix $A$ is $B = \{b_1, b_2, b_3, \ldots, b_n\}$ and $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues $(λ_1, λ_2, λ_3, \ldots, λ_n)$, then $A$ is diagonalizable with $A = PDP^{-1}$, where $P$ has column vectors $[b_1 b_2 b_3 \ldots b_n]$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues $(λ_1, λ_2, λ_3, \ldots, λ_n)$.

TRUE, SOMETIMES, or FALSE?

Comment: you seem confused: "a basis for matrix A" doesn't make sense. matrices don't have bases; vector spaces do. but for what it's worth, any $n\times n$ matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues is always diagonalizable.

Comment: I wan't sure how to phase it as a short descriptive question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the wording to "$B=\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{C}^n$) consisting of eigenvectors of $A$, and $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $b_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$", then the statement is always true.  You don't even need that the eigenvalues are distinct.

Comment: so the statement I have above is false, without changing the wording?

Comment: @BobR: that question is unanwerable because it's not clear what your question, as it's currently written, is asking.

Comment: in other words, Alistair is suggesting one way to make your question meaningful. one thing you might be asking is: if the eigenvectors of $A$ form a basis ${b_i}$, and the eigenvector $b_i$ has eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, then does $P=[b_i]$ diagonalize $A$ to have diagonal entries $\lambda_i$? the answer to *that* question is "always true."

Comment: Um is the statement true, false or sometimes true? I Sorry but that's the exact wording that was provided lol. In its state I would then conclude false.

Comment: then whoever wrote the question is confused. the question, as written, doesn't make sense, so you can't decide its truth value. it's like asking whether "colorless green ideas sleep furiously" is true, false, or sometimes true. what Alistair and I have suggested is one way to make the sentence mean something, but you have to decide whether our interpretation really is what was meant.

Comment: The statement has no meaning as given since matrices don't have bases.  It's like asking "Is the King of the USA tall?"